# loading images from cdn in angular-cli

Tags: angular-cli

How to give a common cdn path to load images in a project developed using angular-cli. Had we been using webpack, then there is an option by setting the `publicPath: '/',` in the output of webpack.config.js. How to set a commong cdn for my images, I am using angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.15

Thank you